# Doxygen sees global variable declarations as functions in C++

Tags: c++, doxygen

When I run Doxygen (1.8.15), I get warnings in the log file that state that not all parameters of a function are documented:

```
warning: parameters of member gSwInstallIoMgr are not (all) documented
warning: return type of member gSwInstallIoMgr is not documented
```

The "Functions" in question are not functions, but are variable declarations:

```
//! This defines the handler for processing changes to the SW installation.
SwInstallIoMgr gSwInstallIoMgr(gsIoMgrDictionary.mMainPcba.mSwInstall);
```

I tried adding the @var command to specify it is a variable:

```
//! @var SwInstallIoMgr gSwInstallIoMgr
//! This defines the handler for processing changes to the SW installation.
SwInstallIoMgr gSwInstallIoMgr(gsIoMgrDictionary.mMainPcba.mSwInstall);
```

But then I get a warning that the function is not documented.

Anyone know a way to fix this?

Edit: Adding some more context

```
//! @brief Software Installation interface class definition.

class SwInstallIoMgr : public Observer
{
public:
   //! @brief Constructor.
   //! @param[in] rIoParams This provides items used for user communication.
   SwInstallIoMgr(SwInstallIoMgrParams & rIoParams);

   //! @brief Destructor.
   virtual ~SwInstallIoMgr();
}
```

`gsIoMgrDictionary` is a global object that contains shared data.

```
IoManagerParams gsIoMgrDictionaryInstance; //!< Dictionary instance for ioMgr
IoManagerParams& gsIoMgrDictionary = gsIoMgrDictionaryInstance; //!< reference to dictionary
```

`IoManagerParams` is a glorified data structure.

Reproducible Example:
BoxBase.h

```
#ifndef BOX_BASE_H
#define BOX_BASE_H

//! @brief BoxBase is a base for the Box
class BoxBase
{
public:

   //! Set of notification policy bits for a Box instance.
   enum NotifyFlags
   {
      //! Notify observers when Box::Attach() method is called.
      NOTIFY_ON_ATTACH = 0x01,

      //! Notify observers when Box::Set() method is called.
      NOTIFY_ON_SET = 0x02,

      //! Notify observers when Box::Set() method is called and the
      //! Box value has changed, or more precisely when C::operator!=
      //! returns true.
      NOTIFY_ON_CHANGE = 0x04
   };

}
```

Box.h

```
#ifndef BOX_H
#define BOX_H

//! @brief A Box
template <class C> class Box: public BoxBase
{
   //! @brief Box constructor with an initial value and notification
   //! policy.
   //!
   //! A copy of the initial value object object is managed by the
   //! box.
   //!
   //! @param[in] c Initial value of the box.
   //! @param[in] notifyFlags Box<>::NotifyFlags type or'd together.
   explicit Box(const C& c,
                int notifyFlags = (NOTIFY_ON_CHANGE | NOTIFY_ON_ATTACH));

private:
   // The box value.
   C mVal;

   // The box value when constructed.
   C mInitialValue;

   // An or composition of NotifyFlags maintaining the Box
   // notification policy. Defined mutable since it does not
   // participate in the equality operator.
   mutable int mNotifyFlags;

   // Marker that the Box contents have been changed via Set() after the
   // previous Get(). If yes this flag is set to true, otherwise false.
   // Defined mutable since it does not participate in the equality
   // operator.
   mutable bool mHasChanged;
};

template <class C>
Box<C>::Box(const C& ival, int notifyFlags):
   BoxBase(), mVal(ival), mInitialValue(ival),
   mNotifyFlags(notifyFlags), mHasChanged(false)
{}

#endif
```

TestFile.h

```
//****************************************************************************
//! @file
//! @brief A Box group stuff.
//!
//! Copyright (C) 2016 MyCompany, Inc. All rights reserved.
//****************************************************************************
#include "Box.h"

namespace Dictionary
{
   namespace OtherSettingsGroup
   {
      //! Informing GUI of current reminder period.
      extern Box<int> toGUIReminder;

      //! GUI informing GUI of new reminder period.
      extern Box<int> toApplicationReminder;

      //! Tells Application to update the values in the OtherSettings group.
      extern Box<bool> toApplicationUpdateOtherSettings;
   }
}
```

TestFile.cpp

```
//****************************************************************************
//! @file
//! @brief A Box group for stuff.
//!
//! Copyright (C) 2016 MyCompany, Inc. All rights reserved.
//****************************************************************************

#include "TestFile.h"

namespace Dictionary
{
   namespace OtherSettingsGroup
   {
      Box<int> toGUIReminder(int(0), BoxBase::NOTIFY_ON_SET);

      Box<int> toApplicationReminder(int(0), BoxBase::NOTIFY_ON_SET);

      Box<bool> toApplicationUpdateOtherSettings(bool(false), 
                                                 BoxBase::NOTIFY_ON_SET);
   }
}
```

This example produces two warnings:

```
TestFile.cpp:14: warning: Member toGUIReminder(int(0), BoxBase::NOTIFY_ON_SET) (function) of namespace Dictionary::OtherSettingsGroup is not documented.
TestFile.cpp:16: warning: Member toApplicationReminder(int(0), BoxBase::NOTIFY_ON_SET) (function) of namespace Dictionary::OtherSettingsGroup is not documented.
```

Comment: Personally I'd also document your global variables.

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using?

Comment: @john These are global variables, and this is the documentation, so I don't understand your suggestion.

Comment: @albert v1.8.15 (edit: it's 15, not 13)

Comment: When using doxygen 1.8.13 with a new (i.e. doxygen -g) Doxyfile I don't get warnings, nor with 1.8.15. Any special settings in your Doxyfile (just run `doxygen -x`), Also state the warning you get,

Comment: We could probably do with a [MCVE], as usual.

Comment: @albert I will try using a new Doxyfile and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I am not sure if have a good example that is simple enough to post.  It only seems to happen with some declarations, and I don't see the pattern that could be causing it.

Comment: The problem here looks to be brackets, doxygen thinks it is a function. I think it would be good to have a bit more complete MWE (with the class definition etc.)

Comment: @albert I agree, doxygen thinks it's function.  I have added more definitions for context.  What I don't know is what is different about this declaration, since it doesn't error for most similar looking declarations.

Comment: Are the ones that "it  doesn't error for most similar looking declarations" the "IoManagerParams " ones? If so that is clear as theer are no round brackets there.

Comment: @albert Here is another example:

Comment: @albert Sorry, added it to the main post because editing in a comment sucks.

Comment: For the "last function" outside the `#ifndef` I get a warning as well (note there is probably also a  small typo in the last example, shouldn't `toApplicationReminder` be `toAnticoagReminder` or vice versa)

Comment: @DavidK Exactly! We'll need you to work out an example that actually triggers the problem, otherwise we may not be able to help.

Comment: I tried creating an example from this, and I am not getting warnings.  It is apparently only in the full context of my project where I get these parse warnings.

Comment: maybe `doxygen -x` shines a light.

Comment: @albert I got an example working with a fresh Doxyfile, I have updated the post.

Comment: @DavidK I can reproduce the problem, could you make an issue in the doxygen issue tracker (https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/new) includig the 4 files of the last test