# Doxygen misinterpretes instantiation as member

Tags: c++, doxygen

I'm working on a documentation of a source code using Doxygen.

I found that Doxygen interpretes within the following code:

```cpp
#include <QPoint>

namespace space {
   //! first common length
   const quint16 val1 = 10;
   //! second common length
   const quint16 val2 = 10;
   //! a point
   const QPoint myPoint(val1, val2);
}
```

`myPoint` as member method and warns:

```
header.h:30: warning: return type of member space::myPoint is not documented
header.h:30: warning: parameters of member space::myPoint are not (all) documented
```

But `myPoint` is a constant attribute not a method. I think this line really has the same syntax as a method declaration. So this misinterpretation is expectable.

Is there a way to force Doxygen to interprete this line as a specific type?

Comment: Looks like someone was having a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54812028/doxygen-sees-global-variable-declarations-as-functions-in-c

Comment: Yes. Something you did better. I search a lot and found nothing and you found it instantly /o\
But the problem seems not to be solved...

Comment: You should report this as a bug and ask for a workaround there

Comment: I comment on https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/6846

Comment: What happens if you use the Clang compiler with Doxygen?

Comment: What do you mean by this? Does Doxygen use a compiler?

Comment: I set `CLANG_ASSISTED_PARSING = YES` but the warning stays the same.